# Android eclipse Dump SQLite table row into text file

Tags: android, eclipse, file, sqlite, dump

Is there a way to grab database table information in your android app and dump it into a text file?  I know how to create files, but I can't seem to find the correct code to select DB information and dump it into a text file (or even a csv file).

Or am I just going to have to do a manual select statements for every row, grab the data from a cursor, and then write them to a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to look at the .dump command of sqlite. I tried it using command line and it works. You can find details [here](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html).